# load async json settings prior to loading angularjs sub module library

Tags: angularjs

I have a distributed AngularJs library module, that is been used in other AngularJs applications that I have no control over.

After researching I see that For an AngularJs application, you can load a json settings by ajax request and then synchronously bootstrap the app afterward.

For a module I provide for other to use, it is not that simple. Looking at [AngularJs injector code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.7.7/src/auto/injector.js), I don't see any asynchronous mechanism coming into play when loadModules act.

The json will be used to declare a constant provider for my sub module. It changes between different clients.

Has someone else found a trick or solution on how to load json settings for Angularjs module (not application) prior to the module availability to an Angularjs application?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is interested, I have solved my problem by indirect solution. Another script loading tag above the sub module script tag. The other script include building an angular module that provides the constants for the other module which declare its dependency on it.

That way, synchronous order of first loading the configuration module and then the module is preserved. Not a direct solution but good enough for production usage.